# Thread_local cost of unused variable

Tags: c++, thread-local-storage

Variables declared `thread_local` are unique for each thread. But do they consume memory if the function is not called?

Let's say I have a bunch of libraries that have `thread_local` variables in their functions. When I create a thread, are these variables going to be initialized even if I never call the functions that use them?

Example:

```
int lib1_foo()
{
    thread_local int a, b;
    // ...
}

int lib2_bar()
{
     thread_local BigObject c;
    // ...
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t([]() {
        // Do a, b, c consume memory?
        // Are they initialized? 
    )();
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: Could you show an example code of just what kind of variable declaratipn/definition you mean?

Comment: allocation is not the same as initialisation.

Comment: _"...thread_local variables in their functions..."_ unless theses variables are declared `static` this would be strange as each call of the function would get their own locals irrespective of threading.  Please include a [mcve] aid the question.

Comment: _"If `thread_local` is the only storage class specifier applied to a block scope variable, `static` is also implied"_ - from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration). Haven't checked the standard but it seems reasonable

Comment: I mix up with initialization and allocation. First, I would like to know if they consume memory. Second, I would like to know if they consume cpu time for initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They certainly consume memory.  cppreference has [this to say](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) (emphasis mine):

> **thread storage duration:** The storage for the object is allocated *when the thread begins* and deallocated when the thread ends. Each thread has its own instance of the object. Only objects declared thread_local have this storage duration.

As for initialisation, it then goes on to say:

> See **Non-local variables** and **Static local variables** for details on initialization of objects with this storage duration.

From which we get:

> All [non-local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Non-local_variables) with thread-local storage duration are initialized as part of thread launch, sequenced-before the execution of the thread function begins.

And:

> [Static local variables](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Static_local_variables) ... are initialized the first time control passes through their declaration (plus some extra verbiage which is worth reading).